# Trouble with this equality

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

So in one of the combinatorics book I am reading, it says:

$$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)=\sum_{T\subseteq S} \prod_{x_i\in T} x_i$$

Where $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are the elements of the $n$ set $S$, and $T$ is any subset of $S$. My question is, why is the right hand side of the equality the way it is? Because according to the left side, if you expand there should be the terms with $x_i$'s and a $1$, however on the rightside if you expand you dont get a term with $1$, so I dont understand how this equality holds. Can anyone help me clarify my confusion?

Comment: When I expand the right-side, I do get a term equalling $1$.

Comment: That is the part I am confused with, could you please explain to me further how you get that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be a convention where if $T = \emptyset$ then $$\prod_{x_i\in T}x_i=1.$$

See the wikipedia page on empty product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: Is this just really a convention, or is there a mathematical reasoning behind why this is the case?

Comment: After doing a little digging, it appears this is a convention. Look up empty product.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Would you really like to have $\prod_{j=1}^{m+1}a_j\ne a_{m+1}\prod_{j=1}^m a_j$?

Comment: To define the product over empty set as 1 is the only reasonable choice. Think what happens when you add another multiplier to a product.

Comment: Ok thank you for all the help. It was very useful.